# Using Measures for Suppression of Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, filters

Weirdly I have not used Measures much. We have a requirement to not send an Email if the Subscriber has been sent that email in the past 2 days.

Previously I have used the SendLog and we queried data to a 'Suppression' DE to be used as an exclusion in a SQL Activity.

Looking at Measures, I'm thinking creating a Measure that has:

```
Event Source: Sent
Email Name is equal to 'Email name'
Sent Date is after today minus 2 days
```

Then in our Filter for the Audience we have all our Filter Criteria and then add the Measure above with is equal to 0???

My understanding is the Measure only returns data on Subscribers that were Sent. So would this work?

Comment: If queries are a viable option (querying the system data views) I would definitely suggest that route (not to suggest that your scenario will not work). I've run into issues with Measures in the past not returning the expected results, and the typical response from support is that Measures are a legacy feature no longer updated and that SQL queries are recommended instead.

Answer (score 0):

A measure is always a positive count. So you want in your filter criteria 'equal or greater than 1'

This gives you the audience of who you sent the email to in the last 2 days. You then send to your data extension and exclude the audience of your filter/measure result.

Measures/filters can be confusing at first.